# Providing tuple-like structured binding access for a class

Tags: c++, c++17, structured-bindings

I'm trying to support tuple-like structured binding access for a class. For simplicity, I'll use the following class in the rest of this post:

```
struct Test
{
    int v = 42;
};
```

(I'm aware that this class supports structured bindings out of the box but let's assume it does not.)

To [enable tuple-like access](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding) to the member of `Test`, we must specialize `std::tuple_size` and `std::tuple_element`:

```
namespace std
{

template<>
struct tuple_size<Test>
{
    static const std::size_t value = 1;
};

template<std::size_t I>
struct tuple_element<I, Test>
{
    using type = int;
};

}
```

And the last part we need is either `Test::get<i>` or a function `get<i>(Test)` in `Test`'s namespace. Let's implement the latter:

```
template<std::size_t I>
int get(Test t)
{
    return t.v;
}
```

This works. However, I would like to return a reference to `Test`'s member, just like `std::get(std::tuple)`, for example. Therefore, I implement `get` as follows:

```
template<std::size_t I>
int& get(Test& t)
{
    return t.v;
}

template<std::size_t I>
const int& get(const Test& t)
{
    return t.v;
}
```

With this version, however, the following code

```
auto test = Test{};
auto [v] = test;
```

produces an error (GCC 7.1):

> binding reference of type ‘std::tuple_element<0, Test>::type& {aka int&}’ to ‘const int’ discards qualifiers

So it seems as if the `get<i>(const Test&)` overload is selected for the structured binding. Since this overload returns a `const int&`, and `v` acts like a non-`const` reference to `int`, the code fails to compile.

According to [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding), however, the line `auto [v] = test;` should be roughly equivalent to

```
auto e = test;
std::tuple_element<0, Test>::type& v = get<0>(e)
```

Which *does* work since it uses the `get<i>(Test&)` overload.

Any ideas on why my implementation of `get` does not work for structured bindings?

Comment: You forgot "In these initializer expressions, `e` is an lvalue if the type of the entity `e` is an lvalue reference and an xvalue otherwise".

Comment: @Barry The kind of the reference is determined from the value category of the initializer, which is an lvalue (because it ends up using the `const &` overload). Not sure how you want this to be diagnosed...

Comment: @T.C. Yeah, deleted my comment before you even replied :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `auto [v]` is a non-reference declaration, so `test` is copied and the copy of `test` is passed to `get` as an xvalue.

So you need to add an rvalue qualified get:

```
template<std::size_t I>
int&& get(Test&& t)
{
    return std::move(t.v);
}
```

Comment: This indeed seems to solve the problem. However, what happens if multiple values are bound and `get` is called multiple times on the same copy of `test`? It seems to me that, since the copy is passed as an rvalue reference, it may be moved from resulting in undefined behavior the second time `get` is called.

Comment: @Job `get` will be called multiple times on the same object, but with different values of `I`. It's your responsibility to ensure that these calls don't conflict.

Comment: I see, although it does seem error-prone to me. Is this documented somewhere in the standard? Also, is there any reason why the copy isn't simply passed as an lvalue reference?

Comment: @Job no, the Standard doesn't call out this as a potential pitfall; I think that most people would consider a `get<>` that modifies elements other than the indicated one to be broken anyway. Your second question is a very good one (and possibly worthy of a separate SO question); all I can think is that the authors are allowing for a case where rvalue `get` has different (more efficient) behavior to lvalue `get`. Perhaps `get` involves a computation, and rvalue `get` can return a prvalue materializaing that computation. I'm having trouble thinking of a concrete example, though.