# Direct initialization fails with class derived from std::tuple, while it works for std::pair

Tags: c++

from time to time it happens that I want to change a type I defines via **using** by a real class.

For example I here a sample, how I can use a struct the same way as a type:

```
using t_int_pair = std::pair< int, int >;
struct s_int_pair : public std::pair< int, int >
{
    using std::pair< int, int >::pair; // inherit ctor
};

void foo()
{
    auto [a1, a2] = t_int_pair{ 0, 0 };
    auto [b1, b2] = s_int_pair{ 0, 0 };
    // ...
}
```

This works fine.

But: for any reason the same code doesn't work for std::tuple, i.e. this produces a compile error:

```
using t_int_triple = std::tuple< int, int, int >;
struct s_int_triple : public std::tuple< int, int, int >
{
    using std::tuple< int, int, int >::tuple; // inherit ctor
};

void bar()
{
    auto [a1, a2, a3] = t_int_triple{ 0, 0, 0 };
    auto [b1, b2, b3] = s_int_triple{ 0, 0, 0 }; // ERROR: cannot decompose class type 'std::_Tuple_impl<0, int, int>'
    // ...
}
```

Does anyone know, why this happens?

And is there a way to workaround this?

I tested this on Compiler Explorer with clang, gcc and msvc.

Any help is appreciated,

regards,

Zoppo

Comment: No, the initialization works well, what fails is the structured binding.

Comment: There are https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45699005/providing-tuple-like-structured-binding-access-for-a-class and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7967746/tuple-size-and-an-inhereted-class-from-tuple concerning that.

Comment: I am surprised inheriting from std pair allowes structured decomposition to work.  Maybe the public members?  That might be why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I started from splitting the instruction into two parts (with the old-style initialization to bypass any problems related to `std::initailizer_list`, if any):

```
 s_int_triple s( 0, 0, 0 );
 auto [b1, b2, b3] = s;
```

The compiler error reads:

```
main.cpp:27:10: error: cannot decompose class type ‘std::_Tuple_impl<1, int, int>’: its base classes ‘std::_Head_base<2, int, false>’ and ‘std::_Head_base<1, int, false>’ have non-static data members
   27 |     auto [b1, b2, b3] = s;
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

So I conclude that the inheritance of a constructor is not a problem, the problem is with the structured binding.
C++ is an awful language when one has to look at its standard template library, but after loading the program to a decent IDE I found that in the gcc 10,2  implementation of `std::tuple`, this class inherits publicly from `_Tuple_impl<0, _Elements...>` and  privatly from `_Head_base<_Idx, _Head>` (multiple inheritance, recursive in the number of parameters). Now it's time to look for non-static data members of these classes. The first class looks so messy that I failed. The second, however, has this line in its  declaration:

```
_Head _M_head_impl;
```

Bingo! This is a non-static data member.

Now its time to find the appropriate rule of structured binding decomposition. We go to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding and there, straight to "Case 3":

> Every non-static data member of E must be a **direct member of E** or **the same base class of E**, and must be well-formed in the context of the structured binding when named as e.name. E may not have an anonymous union member. The number of identifiers must equal the number of non-static data members.

So here we have the answer: your class that derives from `std::tuple` inherits form several other classes, too, and some of them define nonstatic members.

Simple example of this phenomenon:

```
struct A
{
  int x;
};

struct B: public A
{
  int y;
};

int main()
{
  B obj;
  auto [a, b] = obj;
}
```

leads to

```
main2.cpp:14:8: error: cannot decompose class type ‘B’: both it and its base class ‘A’ have non-static data members
```

So now we come to a real puzzle: if `std::tuple` inherits from different classes, and each defines a nonstatic member, then  why can we use structured binding for tuples? We go back to the cppreference [link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding)   and see that `std::tuple` is an exception to Case 3 described above. Compilers have to treat standard tuples **and similar classes** in their own, special way. In other words, `std::tuple` and tuple-like classes are handled by **Case 2**, but any other class or struct is handled by far more restrictive (and very general) **Case 3**.

So, to make your program compile, you have to make your class "tuple-like", as described in the source cited above. <s>I have no idea if it is possible at all - I guess this would deserve asking a separate question.</s>  How to do it is described in the answer by @yakk-adam-nevraumont

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed information, now I understand why it can't work.

Answer (score 2):

Pair is an aggregate with public members, tuple does not.

Your inherit-from-pair is using the aggregate structured bindings.

Tuple uses the tuple machinery. Some of the tuple machinery doesn't work with inheritance for good reason.

So you need to specialize `std::tuple_size<your_type>` to expose the tuple size.

```
struct s_int_triple : public std::tuple< int, int, int >
{
  using std::tuple< int, int, int >::tuple; // inherit ctor
};
namespace std{
  template<>
  class tuple_size<::s_int_tuple>:public std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 3>{};
  template< std::size_t I >
  class tuple_element<I,::s_int_tuple>:public tuple_element<I, std::tuple<int,int,int>>{};
}
```

and structured binding should work.

Yes this sucks.

Comment: (`std::get` automatically works because the class has `std::tuple` as a base case, right?)

Comment: @user2 yes, overload resolution considers bases, while template specialization does not.

Comment: Thanks a lot ... but I think I won't implement something in std-namespace (afaik C++ standard disallows it).

So I think i will bite the bullet and implement a function and use it wherever it doesn't compile after replacing my types with structs.

Comment: @zoppo You specialziaing certain traits for types dependent on your types is explicitly allowed and by design.  It is how you are supposed to do it.